# Update OUTPUT results when used on a view with an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, triggers

I have a view that combines two tables.  When I do an insert into the view, the trigger gets the primary key/clustered index value using `NEXT VALUE FOR MySequence`.

The trigger then inserts into the two tables using the generated key and the values in the `Inserted` table.  It all works just fine.

The problem comes in when an application that uses the view does an insert with an [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) clause.  Something like this:

```
DECLARE @InsertedIds table (MyViewId int, ValueForTheFirstTable int)

INSERT INTO MyView (ValueForTheFirstTable, ValueForTheSecondTable )
OUTPUT Inserted.MyViewId, Inserted.ValueForTheFirstTable into @InsertedIds
VALUES ('FirstTableValue', 'SecondTableValue')
```

ValueForTheFirstTable does return the correct value.  But the MyViewId (the key) is null.  (And I really expect it to be anything else because it does not know the key that I generated.)

My question is, **how can I modify my `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger to make it so that the `OUTPUT` clause will contain my generated Sequence number value?**

I know value, I just need a way to feed it back to SQL Server so it can provide it to any OUTPUT clauses.

Comment: Can you post your table definition and an example of what you mean? I can't follow this.

Comment: @SeanLange - I appreciate your interest.  But the more I think about it, I don't think what I want is possible. (To update the results of the OUTPUT clause from inside the trigger.)  I am realizing that I would be better off just having the application generate the Key using the sequence and then passing it in as part of the insert.

Comment: Downvote reason: "how can I modify my INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger" - To answer that we will need to see the trigger you have now... You have way too much reputation to not know we need a [mcve]...